# Distinct rows by their values from sub list LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, syntax, distinct

I would like to remove duplicate rows by their values from sub list using LINQ syntax. Below I attached code which does that by different way.

xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

```
List<ZRowCollection> zListCollection = new List<ZRowCollection>();
        zListCollection = zListCollection.OrderBy(p => p.P).ToList();
        int i1 = 1;
        foreach (var item in zListCollection.ToList())
        {
            var subList1 = item.XRowModified.Select(p => p).ToList();
            foreach (var item2 in zListCollection.Skip(i1).ToList())
            {
                var subList2 = item2.XRowModified.Select(p => p).ToList();
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var item3 in subList1)
                {
                    var t2 = subList2.Select(p => p.Average).ToList();
                    decimal average = t2[i];
                    if (item3.Average == average)
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                if (i == item2.XRowModified.Count)
                {
                    zListCollection.Remove(item2);
                }
            }
            i1++;
        }
```

properties

```
class XRowModified
{
    public decimal Id { get; set; }
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public decimal Average { get; set; }
}
class ZRowCollection
{
    public ZRowCollection()
    {
        this.XRowModified = new HashSet<XRowModified>();
    }
    public int P { get; set; }
    public int High { get; set; }
    public int Low { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<XRowModified> XRowModified { get; set; }
}
```

expected input/output,
as a comparer column Average in `List<XRowModified>`

```
List<ZRowCollection> zListInput = new List<ZRowCollection>(){
            new ZRowCollection(){P = 0,High = 4,Low = 0, XRowModified = new List<XRowModified>(){
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1550, Open = 1.22M,High = 1.24M,Low = 1.21M,Close = 1.23M,Average = 1.225M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 23, 23, 222)},
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1551, Open = 1.20M,High = 1.24M,Low = 1.22M,Close = 1.20M,Average = 1.23M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 23, 25, 122)}}},
            new ZRowCollection(){P = 1,High = 3,Low = 0, XRowModified = new List<XRowModified>(){
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1555, Open = 1.22M,High = 1.24M,Low = 1.21M,Close = 1.23M,Average = 1.225M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 23, 40, 422)},
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1556, Open = 1.20M,High = 1.25M,Low = 1.20M,Close = 1.20M,Average = 1.23M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 23, 46, 522)}}},
            new ZRowCollection(){P = 2,High = 2,Low = 0, XRowModified = new List<XRowModified>(){
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1558, Open = 1.22M,High = 1.24M,Low = 1.21M,Close = 1.23M,Average = 1.225M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 30, 11, 622)},
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1559, Open = 1.20M,High = 1.24M,Low = 1.22M,Close = 1.20M,Average = 1.23M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 30, 12, 822)}}}
        };
        List<ZRowCollection> zListOutput = new List<ZRowCollection>(){
            new ZRowCollection(){P = 0,High = 4,Low = 0, XRowModified = new List<XRowModified>(){
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1550, Open = 1.22M,High = 1.24M,Low = 1.21M,Close = 1.23M,Average = 1.225M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 23, 23, 222)},
                    new XRowModified(){ Id = 1551, Open = 1.20M,High = 1.24M,Low = 1.22M,Close = 1.20M,Average = 1.23M,
                        Time = new DateTime(2012, 11, 9, 12, 23, 25, 122)}}}
        };
```

Comment: Wow, how many ToList() call!

Comment: Sorry I forgot remove it, at least some of them, I spent too much time on result accuracy. :)

Comment: The example is a little obtuse, can you post expected input/output?

Comment: @Paul you are telling that you want to remove duplicated items from sub list (by some unclear rule), but in expected output I see items removed from parent list

Comment: It would be easier if you just described (at a high level) what you're looking for where your objects are considered equal. Your code isn't the easiest to read and deciphering it is a challenge. e.g., they are considered equal if they have the same `Id`.

Comment: if(parent1.sub.AverageClumn == parent2.sub.AverageClumn) remove parent2, i mean if all items from parent1.sub.AvaregeColum match to all items from parent2.sub.AvaregeColum then remove parent2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would consider writing a custom equality comparer, which could then be plugged in to the `Distinct` method. To do this you need two functions `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Note: It is important the `GetHashCode` returns the same hash for two equal objects as this is the first thing that `Distinct` checks.

From what I gather from your code two `ZRow`'s are equal if their `XRow`'s have the same sequence of averages, so our equality is that `averageSequence1.SequenceEqual(averageSequence2)` which would be implemented as so:

```
public class CustomComparer : IEqualityComparer<ZRowCollection>
{
    public static CustomComparer Instance { get { return new CustomComparer(); } }

    Int32 IEqualityComparer<ZRowCollection>.GetHashCode(ZRowCollection value)
    {
        //One could also use the sum of the averages here, but went for simplicity...
        return value.XRowModified.Count;
    }

    Boolean IEqualityComparer<ZRowCollection>.Equals(ZRowCollection z1, ZRowCollection z2)
    {
        return z1.XRowModified.Select(x => x.Average)
                              .SequenceEqual(z2.XRowModified.Select(x => x.Average));
    }
}
```

and which would be used like so:

```
var distinctList = zListCollection.Distinct(CustomComparer.Instance);
```